# Filtering multiple arrays using a specific value from another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I am using json feed from google sheet, the json is not really organized so using a loop function to fetch it onto different arrays

These arrays are fetched onto html cards using $.each loop function

the code is in this js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mohalmah/wtydLo3b/9/

I would like to create a function that filters those arrays based on week array

Scenario:

user click a button “November”
then the function will filter all the array values that have “Nov” in it then filter the other arrays (Content,…etc) that has the same location of “Nov” values

then fetch the respective cards to the html

JS:

```
 var week = ['Nov 1', 'Nov 2', 'Dec 1', 'Dec 2', 'Jan 1', 'Jan 2'];
 var content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

 $.each(week.slice(), function(i, data) {
 var ul_data = [

 '<div class="container">' +
 '<div class="flex-container">' +

 '<div class="card">' +
 '<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>' +
 '<div class="card-content">' +
 '<p>Week ' + week[i] + '</p>' +
 '<h1>Cultural Topic</h1>' +
 '<p> Content' + content[i] + '</p>' +
 '</div>' +
 '</div>' +
 '</div>' +
 '</div>'
 ];

 $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this,
based on the word pattern you will have both of your arrays
content and week filtered

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/2bpthxLm/

```js
var week = ['Nov 1', 'Nov 2', 'Dec 1', 'Dec 2', 'Jan 1', 'Jan 2'];
var content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const word = 'Dec'
const indexArr = [];

week = week.filter((x, i) => {
  const hasWord = x.indexOf(word) > -1
  if (hasWord) {
    indexArr.push(i);
  }
  return hasWord;
});
content = content.filter((x, i) => indexArr.includes(i))

console.log(content, week);
```

And here is the full js/jquery working code

```
 var week = ['Nov 1', 'Nov 2', 'Dec 1', 'Dec 2', 'Jan 1', 'Jan 2'];
 var content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


 let word = 'Dec'
 let copyWeek = [];
 let copyContent = [];
 const indexArr = [];

 document.getElementById("button-filter").addEventListener('click', () => {
   word = document.getElementById('search-word').value.trim();
   copyWeek = week.filter((x, i) => {
     const hasWord = x.indexOf(word) > -1
     if (hasWord) {
       indexArr.push(i);
     }
     return hasWord;
   });
   copyContent = content.filter((x, i) => indexArr.includes(i))
   if (!week.length) {
     populateList(week, content);
   } else {
     populateList(copyWeek, copyContent);
   }

 })

 populateList(week,content)

 function populateList(week, content) {
   $('#recentActivities').empty();
   $.each(week, function(i, data) {
     var ul_data = [

       '<div class="container">' +
       '<div class="flex-container">' +

       '<div class="card">' +
       '<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>' +
       '<div class="card-content">' +
       '<p>Week ' + week[i] + '</p>' +
       '<h1>Cultural Topic</h1>' +


       '<p> Content' + content[i] + '</p>' +

       '</div>' +
       '</div>' +


       '</div>' +
       '</div>'
     ];

     $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);

   });
 }
```

Comment: amazing, thanks bro .. Will try your solution on the original project .. Can u make it a drop down list instead of text input .. so any one can choose the month and it automatically filter the cards

Comment: I updated the fiddle, it's better now, when you filter again you won't loose the data

Comment: yeah, that's better I was trying to solve that .. very genius  .. canu give example if that can be done from a dropdown list? or buttons?